# How do I fix the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'...when looping

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner and answers on this forum have been invaluable.  I am using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup to scrape (non-table) data from multiple web pages on the same website by looping the page number.  It works but I keep getting the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' after the first iteration.

Here is the code I have tried thus far:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv

import lxml


# Lists to store the scraped data in

addresses = []
geographies = []
rents = []
units = []
availabilities = []

# Scraping all pages

pages_url = requests.get('https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments')

pages_soup = BeautifulSoup(pages_url.text, 'html.parser')

list_nums = pages_soup.find('div', class_='_1y05u').text

print(list_nums)

pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,8)]

for page in pages:

    response = requests.get('https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=' + page).text

    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')


    # Extract data from individual listing containers

    listing_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='_3PdAH')
    print(type(listing_containers))
    print(len(listing_containers))



    for container in listing_containers:
        address = container.a.text
        addresses.append(address)

        geography = container.find('div', class_='_1dhrl').text
        geographies.append(geography)

        rent = container.find('div', class_='_3e12V').text
        rents.append(rent)

        unit = container.find('div', class_='_2tApa').text
        units.append(unit)

        availability = container.find('div', class_='_2P6xE').text
        availabilities.append(availability)

        import pandas as pd
        test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Street' : addresses,
                                'City-State-Zip' : geographies,
                                'Rent' : rents,
                                'BR/BA' : units,
                                'Units Available' : availabilities

        })
        print(test_df)
```

Here is the output:

```
240 Properties
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
                     Street                      City-State-Zip     Rent                 BR/BA    Units Available
0  Quarry Place at Tuckahoe  64 Midland PlaceTuckahoe, NY 10707  $2,490+  1–2 Beds • 1–2 Baths  2 Units Available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renttucktabletest.py", line 60, in <module>
    availability = container.find('div', class_='_2P6xE').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The result I am looking for is **all 240 listings in the pandas dataframe exactly like the first iteration shown in the output above.**  Can anyone help to fix this error?  Would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: It means there is no `div` with that class in the HTML you parsed.

Comment: Given the random names, I'm assuming these are generated and randomised. Have you got any other means of locating the right div?

Comment: First problem listing is "Rivervue" on [page 5](https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=5). There isn't a 'unit' `div`

Comment: Thank you Martijn, yes, as I am reading through these answers it is clear that some of the div's have no information and that seems to be the problem.  As for the random names, The names are not 'random' but they do change frequently, not sure if they are random

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup get\_text returns NoneType object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687872/beautifulsoup-get-text-returns-nonetype-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, the issue is some of the containers are missing certain `div` elements. eg no 'unit' or 'availability' information.

One way to deal with this would be to use `if - else` statements. Append only if the element exists, else append a `NaN` value. Something like:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv

import lxml


# Lists to store the scraped data in

addresses = []
geographies = []
rents = []
units = []
availabilities = []

# Scraping all pages

pages_url = requests.get('https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments')

pages_soup = BeautifulSoup(pages_url.text, 'html.parser')

list_nums = pages_soup.find('div', class_='_1y05u').text

print(list_nums)

pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,8)]

for page in pages:

    response = requests.get('https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=' + page).text

    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')


    # Extract data from individual listing containers

    listing_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='_3PdAH')
    print(type(listing_containers))
    print(len(listing_containers))



    for container in listing_containers:
        address = container.a
        if address:
            addresses.append(address.text)
        else:
            addresses.append(np.nan)

        geography = container.find('div', class_='_1dhrl')
        if geography:
            geographies.append(geography.text)
        else:
            geographies.append(np.nan)

        rent = container.find('div', class_='_3e12V')
        if rent:
            rents.append(rent.text)
        else:
            rents.append(np.nan)

        unit = container.find('div', class_='_2tApa')
        if unit:
            units.append(unit.text)
        else:
            units.append(np.nan)

        availability = container.find('div', class_='_2P6xE')
        if availability:
            availabilities.append(availability.text)
        else:
            availabilities.append(np.nan)

import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Street' : addresses,
                        'City-State-Zip' : geographies,
                        'Rent' : rents,
                        'BR/BA' : units,
                        'Units Available' : availabilities

})
print(test_df)

                     Street                      City-State-Zip     Rent  \
0  Quarry Place at Tuckahoe  64 Midland PlaceTuckahoe, NY 10707  $2,490+   
1     address not disclosed                  Tuckahoe, NY 10707   $2,510   
2     address not disclosed                  Tuckahoe, NY 10707   $4,145   
3        60 Washington St 1  60 Washington StTuckahoe, NY 10707   $3,500   
4        269 Columbus Ave 5  269 Columbus AveTuckahoe, NY 10707   $2,700   

                  BR/BA    Units Available  
0  1–2 Beds • 1–2 Baths  2 Units Available  
1        1 Bed • 1 Bath                NaN  
2       2 Beds • 2 Bath                NaN  
3       3 Beds • 2 Bath                NaN  
4       2 Beds • 1 Bath                NaN
```

Comment: Chris A Thank you!  This works very well, I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 1):

If you pull the info from a script tag and treat as json that problem goes away. None or 0 is returned from the json where had you been trying for class name etc you would have got an error.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd

def add_records(url, s):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
    r = re.compile(r'window.__APPLICATION_CONTEXT__ = (.*)')
    data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
    script = r.findall(data)[0]
    items = json.loads(script)['store']['listings']['listings']

    for item in items:   
        street = item['address']
        geography = ', '.join([item['city'], item['state'], item['zipCode']])
        rent = item['aggregates']['prices']['low']
        BR_BA = 'beds: ' + str(item['aggregates']['beds']['low'])  + ' , ' + 'baths: ' + str(item['aggregates']['baths']['low'])
        units = item['aggregates']['totalAvailable']
        listingId = item['listingId']
        url = base_url + item['listingSeoPath']
        # all_info = item
        record = {'Street' : street,
                  'Geography' : geography,
                  'Rent' : rent,
                  'BR/BA' : BR_BA,
                  'Units Available' : units,
                  'ListingId' : listingId,
                  'Url' : url}
        results.append(record)

url = 'https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page={}'
base_url = 'https://www.rent.com/'
results = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1, 9):
        add_records(url.format(page), s)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = [ 'Street', 'Geography', 'Rent', 'BR/BA', 'Units Available', 'ListingId', 'Url'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr, I very much appreciate the explanation, but I am not quite ready to use json as I am just starting out, but I will keep this in mind when I get to json soon.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to achieve the same.

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page={}'.format(page) for page in range(1,9)]

def get_content(links):
    for url in links:
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        for items in soup.select("._3PdAH"):
            d = {}
            d['address'] = items.select_one("[data-tid='property-title']").text
            try:
                d['geographies'] = items.select_one("[data-tid='listing-info-address']").text
            except AttributeError: d['geographies'] = ""
            try:
                d['rent'] = items.select_one("[data-tid='price']").text
            except AttributeError: d['rent'] = ""
            try:
                d['units'] = items.select_one("[data-tid='beds-baths']").text
            except AttributeError: d['units'] = ""
            try:
                d['availabilities'] = items.select_one("[data-tid='property-unitAvailText']").text
            except AttributeError: d['availabilities'] = ""
            dataframe.append(d)

    return dataframe

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataframe = []
    item = get_content(urls)
    df = pandas.DataFrame(item)
    df.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much SIM.  This code is a little bit too advanced for my level, but I see the basic logic of it.  I will try this out when I get some more hours of coding under my belt.  Thank you again!